# string options when using argparse with python

Tags: python, argparse

I'm not quite understanding the following behavior of argparse

```
parser.add_argument("-option1", type=int, nargs='?', const=1, default=1, choices=xrange(1, 20), help="help message of option1")
parser.add_argument("-option2", type=str, nargs=1, help="help message of option2")
```

in case of option1, args.option1 is an integer, when provided.
in case of option2, args.option2 looks like an array of strings. I have to use args.option2[0] if I want to get the actual string passed with option2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained directly in the documentation on [`nargs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs). Summarizing:

For `nargs=N`, if `N` is an integer, you get a list of `N` values. Even if `N` is `1`.

For `nargs='?'`, you get a single value (which may be the default).

For `nargs` left off entirely, you get whatever the default is for the action. If the action is, e.g., `store`, that means a single value, not a list of one value.

It even explicitly points out exactly the part that's surprised you:

> Note that nargs=1 produces a list of one item. This is different from the default, in which the item is produced by itself.